# How to create a new array from child object properties

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array:

```
[
    {
        meta:'abc'
        data:
        {
            name:'asd',
            title: 'bbb'
        }
    },
    {
        meta:'abc'
        data:
        {
            name:'asd',
            title: 'bbb'
        },
    {
        meta:'abc'
        data:
        {
            name:'asd',
            title: 'bbb'
        }
    }
]
```

I want to convert it to new array, which will be:

```
[
    {
        name:'asd',
        title: 'bbb'
    },
    {
        name:'asd',
        title: 'bbb'
    {
        name:'asd',
        title: 'bbb'
    }
]
```

I want to take only the data elements, and to create from them a new array.
How can I do it the fastest way? And how can I do it with lodash?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you care how fast it is? Are you programming on a Commodore 64?

Comment: I'd assume that the OP means "the cleanest way".

Comment: Where are you stuck? Do you not know how to loop over an array and do something with each of its elements? Do you not know the equivalent lodash utility? Are you stuck writing the logic for what to do with each element, namely extracting its `data` property? By the way, you tagged this "JSON", but it has nothing to do with JSON, which a string-based format for exchanging information.

Comment: I mean the cleanest way. Got an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`_.map`](https://lodash.com/docs#map)

```js
var array = [{
  meta: 'abc',
  data: {
    name: 'asd',
    title: 'bbb'
  }
}, {
  meta: 'abc',
  data: {
    name: 'asd',
    title: 'bbb'
  }
}, {
  meta: 'abc',
  data: {
    name: 'asd',
    title: 'bbb'
  }
}];

console.log(_.map(array, 'data'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.2.0/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Just you need is the map() native javascript method to arrays:

```
//considere that 'someArray' is the same as your.

var newArray = someArray.map(function(item){
    return {name: item.data.name, title: item.data.title};
});
```